# python cmd line application with blessings and cmd

Tags: python, cmd, command-line-interface

I would like to write cmd-line application with Python, which in the upper part of the terminal shows the status of something, I'd like to monitor, while in the lower part I (and my colleages) have the normal ipython interpreter, which allows us to manipulate the behaviour of the application.

In order to show the status display, I was thinking of using [blessings](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/blessings). At first I thought about using [cmd](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cmd.html) or [cmd2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cmd2) in order to allow run-time manipulation of the status display, but then I though, why should one implement a lot of `do_something` methods, when one can have the same functionality (including tab-completion and online help) for free, using the ipython interpreter.

Here is my first approach

```
## -- first_try.py
import time
import random
from threading import Thread
from blessings import Terminal
term = Terminal()

def display_func1():
    print time.asctime()
    print "Some int: ", random.randint(0, 10)
    print "Some float: ", random.random()*10

def display_func2():
    print time.asctime()
    print "Some int: ", random.randint(0, 10)
    print "    details:", [random.randint(0, 10) for i in range(7)]
    print "Some float: ", random.random()*10
    print "    details:", [random.random()*10 for i in range(5)]


class StatusDisplay(Thread):
    def __init__(self, display_func):
        self._text = ""
        self._stop = False
        self.display = display_func
        Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        while not self._stop:
            with term.location():
                self.clear_top_lines()
                print term.move(0, 0)
                print 70*'-'
                self.display()
                print 70*'-'
                self.print_help()
            time.sleep(0.1)

    def stop(self):
        self._stop = True

    def print_help(self):
        print 
        print "In order to manipulate the status display"
        print "type: "
        print "   sd.display = display_func2       and if you want to go back."
        print "   sd.display = display_func1"
        print "    Or implement your own display function and hook it into the display"

    def clear_top_lines(self, n=10):
        with term.location():
            for i in range(n):
                print term.move(0, i) + term.clear_eol()

time.sleep(2)
sd = StatusDisplay(display_func1)
sd.daemon = True
sd.start()
```

When I invoke this script, e.g. like this:

```
ipython -i --no-banner first_try.py
```

And hit a couple of times enter, then I have in the top of the page, something that looks like the status display, I'd like to have, and in the lower part, I can still work with the ipython interpreter, due to the `-i` parameter.

---

I think I am working here in the wrong direction, but I really would like to have this kind of feature in my application. Can somebody give me a push into the right direction?